# Logstash output as json with custom string prefix

Tags: json, logstash

We need to pass our log messages as syslog format with 2 constraints:

- Message should be prefixed by a custom message (prefix) from the tag field
- Message (after prefix) should be the full parsed input as Json enclosed with `'`.

Input message sample:

```
2016-05-18T17:54:12.098+0000 I ACCESS   [conn104] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
```

Output syslog message sample:

```
May 18 17:56:43 myhostname mongo[-]: some/prefix/I/need/to/show '{"version":"1.1","host":"myhostname","level":6,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-05-18T17:56:43.515Z","source_host":"10.1.1.1","message":"2016-05-18T17:54:12.098+0000 I ACCESS   [conn104] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local","command":"/entrypoint.sh mongod --config /data/configdb/mongod.conf","container_id":"9f5217cf462bf90d4fd2d0ce2d713250637309e9964412421599bc50c8c84977","container_name":"mongo","created":"2016-05-18T17:10:05.720691937Z","image_id":"sha256:297b722a18ce154bd2aa21ddad2f128ea3025f38df2c5a87c7c10faabd4b32a2","image_name":"myregistry/mongodb:3.0","tag":"some/prefix/I/need/to/show"}'
```

I can obtain the second point using something like, but I fail to enclose json in `'` add add the prefix.

```
input {
  gelf { }
}

output {
        syslog {
            facility => "daemon"
            host => "some.loghost.server"
            port => 514
            protocol => "tcp"
            severity => "notice"
            appname => "%{container_name}"
            codec => json_lines
        }
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

Edit 2016-05-19:
I get something by chaining 2 logstash.
Is there a better way?

Conf 1:

```
input {
  gelf { }
}   

output {
        syslog {
            facility => "daemon"
            host => "127.0.0.1"
            port => 1515
            protocol => "tcp"
            severity => "notice"
            appname => "%{tag}"
            codec => json_lines
        }
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }   
}
```

Conf 2:

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 1515
  }
}

filter {    
  grok { pattern => "^%{DATA:tag}\[-\]: %{GREEDYDATA:jsonstring}" }
  mutate { replace => [ "message", "%{jsonstring}" ]  }
  mutate { remove => "jsonstring" }
}           

output {    
        syslog {
            facility => "daemon"
            host => "some.other.logserver"
            port => 514
            protocol => "tcp"
            severity => "notice"
            appname => ""
            msgid => ""
            message => "%{tag} '%{message}'"
        }
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

Comment: The better way is writing your own output filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_output_plugin.html.

Comment: I have to learn Ruby :'(

Comment: It is actually not that difficult if you have programming experience :)